# Why did Mozilla Firefox decide to make the minimum window width to 450px?

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, mozilla

I'm wondering why the browser Mozilla Firefox decided to set the minimum sizable width of its window to 438px. Is there any particular reason for this?
Because if I were to develop responsive website, Chromium browsers have minimum width of 500px.

How to replicate:

1. Open Firefox
2. Right click inside a website
3. Select "Inspect Element"
4. Click on the top right corner beside the phone icon to show more options
5. Select "Separate Window"
6. Resize the browser
7. Note: Remove the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread should explain this value: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=897160

TLDR;
Shrinking the window "too much" would cause UI bugs, so it was decided to set a fixed minimum browser width [image]

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you for sending the very accurate link. You did a good job/